# Android Studio AVD Emulator crashes

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Coming back in the new week, nothing changed on anything but the AVD I was using doesn't work anymore.

the only hint i get is the AVD Event Log:

> 10:29 Emulator: Screenshot failed to find cb 0

I tried reinstalling Android Studio, as well as the SDKs for Android.
Tried using different SDKs, creating new devices.
Nothing worked.

Let me know if you have an idea.

Cheers

Comment: Reinstall the emulator

Comment: I reinstalled AS completly aswell as the devices or what do you mean with emulator?

Comment: In AVD manager.

Comment: I think either we are not on the same page about what we are talking or I just dont get what you recommend. I deleted and reinstalled the devices in AVD Manager and reinstalled the different Android SDKs (29 and R) aswell

Comment: Can you provide more info?